# how to do volume share from two external machines

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have my jenkins configured in Machine A and now I have set up Appium Android docker in machine B via docker compose file. The selenium grid is with one host file and an android emulator.I need to share the apk from machine A to the android emulator in machine B. I can do using the command

```
docker cp file <docker id>:location
```

But I wanted to do as a Volume share basis. So my doubt is to the docker compose file in machine B, how can i share the host folder from machine A. Can I give ip address ?

I tried with this command, but it takes the machine in which docker compose file is present, ie Machine B :

```
- $PWD/example/sample_apk:/root/tmp/sample_apk
```

But I want to share from machine A. How I can do that ? Please help

Comment: Docker doesn't have this capability on its own.  Rather than trying to manage this purely via Docker volumes, can you `scp` the file to the remote host, or build it into an image that you push to a registry?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine 2 scenarios:

```
### A (host machine) & B (is a container in the A host)
version: '3'
services:
  Appium:
    .......
    volumes:
        ##this are directories where the archive gonna be create and sharing
      - /host/root/directory/sample_apk:/container/directory/sample_apk
```

.

```
### A & B Dockerize in a the same host
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    .......
    volumes:
      - sharedApk:/container/directory/create_apk

  Appium:
    .......
    volumes:
      - sharedApk:/container/directory/share_apk 
volumes:
  - sharedApk:
```

Sorry for my english. Bye